# Select entire column as range (in worksheet 2) based on user's input i.e 'header name' in a cell / inputbox (in worksheet 1) using vba

Tags: vba, excel

```
Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet

Dim x As Range

Dim valX, valY

Set ws1 = Sheets("Sheet")

valX=ws1.Range("a1").Value

Set x = ws2.Range("a1:J1").Find(What:=valX,LookIn:=xlValues,lookat:=xlWhole)
```

Above code helps me find the header in new worksheet but i am clueless about selecting the column as Range .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should select the column, however, remember select is not a good practice in VBA -*Disclaimer: in most cases*-

```
ws2.Select    
Columns(x.column).Select
```

Comment: any other way through which i can choose the column and assign it to a range and also input is taken from user in inputbox ?

Comment: Why not to set x as that instead of the find? Like:  Set x = Columns(ws2.Range("a1:J1").Find(What:=valX,LookIn:=xlValues,lookat:=xlWhole).Column)

Comment: makes sense. and can user input be accepted using inputbox ?

Comment: You meant like inputbox for range? If so, try Application.InputBox("Select the range", "TitleInputbox", Type:=8) 'type 8 means for range